# No mysql é possivel criar uma linha extra se 2 ou mais linhas forem iguais

Tags: mysql

Olá gostaria de saber se é possivel criar uma quarta linha para o mysql com base nos Títulos que se repetem como na primeira tabela onde o jogo The Witcher® 3: Wild Hunt repete 3 vezes e sejá gerado a 4 linha com base na segunda tabela ?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Plataforma </th>
            <th>Preço</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</td>
            <td>Pc</td>
            <td>R$ 50</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</td>
            <td>XOne</td>
            <td>R$ 67</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</td>
            <td>Ps4</td>
            <td>R$  80</td>     
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
<h1>Tabela de Exemplo abaixo</h1>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th>Plataforma </th>
        <th>Preço</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt</td>
            <td>Pc/XOne/Ps4</td>
            <td colspan="3" >R$ 50(PC) R$ 67(XOne) R$ 80(Ps4)</td>      
        </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Você precisa agrupar as colunas pelo título do jogo, neste caso basta utilizar o `GROUP BY` em conjunto com o `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Ex:

```
SELECT
    titulo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(plataforma SEPARATOR ', ') AS plataforma,
    GROUP_CONCAT(preco SEPARATOR ', ') AS preco
FROM
    jogos
GROUP BY
    titulo;
```

Caso queira trazer os registros separados e no final, na mesma query, trazer uma linha agrupado, pode fazer as duas querys e juntar por `UNION`.

Ex:

```
SELECT
    titulo,
    plataforma,
    preco
FROM
    jogos
UNION ALL
SELECT
    titulo,
    GROUP_CONCAT(plataforma SEPARATOR ', ') AS plataforma,
    GROUP_CONCAT(preco SEPARATOR ', ') AS preco
FROM
    jogos
GROUP BY
    titulo;
```

Aqui tem um fiddle com estes exemplos em ação: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9Nndvt5Eix1RNW7RMJo7C/0

Ler mais sobre:
[GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
[UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)